# Nginx reverse proxy for nextcloud not work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I need to use nextcloud with reverse proxy (virtual path), and i can't understand where i made a mistake.
It is my config (after some simplifications)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location ^~ /path/ {
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://nextcloud/;
        }
}
```

Nextcloud is working correctly on path `http://nextcloud/`, but on `http://my-domain/path` it is not working.
[image]

I think, this is happening because it is necessary to set `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header, but i can not find any usage example. Can anybody help?

[It is](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/14/admin_manual/configuration_server/reverse_proxy_configuration.html) documentation about nextcloud reverse proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change nginx config. There is special parameter for proxy in nextcloud config.php - `overwritewebroot`. See https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html